# Find the right tensorflow wheel for your raspberry pi

Tags: pi-4, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye

How do I find the right wheel for my raspberry pi? The following are the configurations-

```
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="11"
VERSION="11 (bullseye)"
VERSION_CODENAME=bullseye
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"
```

The architecture is `armv7l`

I tried this- `pip3 install https://dl.google.com/coral/python/tflite_runtime-2.1.0.post1-cp37-cp37m-linux_armv7l.whl` among some other random things and nothing has worked. I just get the error- `ERROR: tflite_runtime-2.1.0.post1-cp37-cp37m-linux_armv7l.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.`

Answer (score 0):

*Raspberry Pi OS - Bullseye* has python 3.9 (not 3.7).

If there is no wheel for *Raspberry Pi OS - Bullseye* pip3 should build from source if you don't try to force it to use an incorrect wheel.